# LKM: Extract cpu model name from /proc/cpuinfo

Tags: c, linux, kernel, string-processing

I wrote a small LKM that opens the `/proc/cpuinfo` file, reads it line by line, and attempts to the cpu model name.
If the function fails to extract the cpu model name, or for some reason it can't read the cpuinfo file, it should return "N/A".

While I am aware that I can also achieve this with a user-space application, I would like to do it within the LKM. I find string processing inside a LKM quiet challenging.

I appreciate any feedback. I am especially interested in the following aspects:

- **String-Processing**: Can the extraction of the cpu model name string be simplified?
- **Edge cases**: Are there any edge cases that aren't covered, that could lead to memory leaks or crashes?

Below is the LKM code, and a Makefile.

**test.c**

```
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/printk.h>
#include <linux/types.h>
#include <linux/path.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("test");


static int lkm_init(void);
char *get_cpu_model_name(void);
static void lkm_exit(void);

static int lkm_init(void) {
    pr_info("Initializing\n");
    pr_info("cpu: %s\n", get_cpu_model_name());
    return 0;
}

char *get_cpu_model_name(void) {
    const char *filename = "/proc/cpuinfo";
    struct file *file = filp_open(filename, O_RDONLY, 0);
    if (IS_ERR(file)) {
        return "N/A";
    }

    // Alloc buffer
    char *buffer = kmalloc(PAGE_SIZE, GFP_KERNEL);
    if (!buffer) {
        filp_close(file, NULL);
        return "N/A";
    }

    ssize_t bytes_read;
    char *newline_pos;
    while ((bytes_read = kernel_read(file, buffer, PAGE_SIZE - 1, &file->f_pos)) > 0) {
        // Ensure buffer has null terminator at the end.
        buffer[bytes_read] = '\0';
        // Process each line
        char *line = buffer;
        while ((newline_pos = strchr(line, '\n')) != NULL) {
            *newline_pos = '\0';
            // Check if the line starts with "model name"
            if (strncmp(line, "model name", 10) == 0) {
                // Skip until ":"
                char *colon_pos = strchr(line, ':');
                if (colon_pos != NULL) {
                    // Skip ":" and ""
                    colon_pos += 2;
                    return colon_pos;
                }
            }
            line = newline_pos + 1;
        }
        memset(buffer, 0, PAGE_SIZE);
    }
    kfree(buffer);
    filp_close(file, NULL);
    return "N/A";
}

static void lkm_exit(void) {
    pr_info("Unloading\n");
}

module_init(lkm_init);
module_exit(lkm_exit);
```

**Makefile**

```
obj-m := test.o
all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

Compile the LKM using `make`, and load it with `sudo insmod test.ko`. Observe the output in dmesg: `sudo dmesg`. Afterwards, unload the LKM with `sudo rmmod test`.

Comment: Everybody manually saving a makefile probably knows this, but: those indentations in the maefile **must** be tabs, not spaces.

Comment: @Davislor Yes, I am aware - I have the Makefile indentation with tabs on my end. I assume while formatting the Makefile it for this post, that got lost :)

Comment: You did, of course. Or it would never have worked!That warning was for anyone else who tried to copy-and-paste.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`get_cpu_model_name()` should define
a string constant for `"N/A"`
which can be used by both it and its consumers.

---

There are multiple calls to `filp_close()`
which should be handled using the `goto out`
resource cleanup idiom.

---

It's not obvious to me that, on a multi-core machine,
the text will always fit within PAGE_SIZE.
Put another way, you could consider allocating a buffer
that you're confident can hold more than a line of text,
and then stream your way through the file with multiple reads.
We might declare support for lines up to length 127,
allocate three 128-byte buffers,
and use the first two as read() bounce buffers
while get_line() copies each line out to the third.
This would force us to skip most of the rather long
"flags:" line, or we could choose bigger constants
if parsing that was of interest.

Alternatively, perhaps there is a code assumption that
should be explicitly documented:
"All occurrences of 'model name' are specified to
have identical content, and the first occurrence is
guaranteed to appear within PAGE_SIZE of the beginning."

---

```
            if (strncmp(line, "model name", 10) == 0) {
```

This is clear enough.
But still, 10 is a
[magic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)).
A manifest string constant or even a simple macro
would be an improvement and would DRY this up a bit.

Maybe the toolchain permits compiler const expressions?

---

```
                    // Skip ":" and ""
```

Code defect: some comments **lie**, including this one.
Author's intent was `" "` rather than `""`.

It's not terrible that we don't verify a SPACE character
at that position. But I wouldn't mind seeing that sanity check, for example by using strstr().
Also, we might verify the return value points at a non-SPACE character.
Returning a truncated CPU name seems kind of OK,
but returning a zero-length name would be bad.
Come to think of it, maybe by bad luck the `:` colon
appears at end of buffer, and you wrote a `'\0'` zero
on top of the subsequent SPACE, leading to
invalid return address.

```
                    return colon_pos;
```

This is correct code, but it's not terrific.
That is, sometimes identifiers lie, as we see here.
This was a beautiful, informative, accurate identifier
when we assigned strchr() to it.
Here, I recommend omitting the increment and simply doing

```
                    return colon_pos + 2;
```

which is perfectly accurate.

---

```
        memset(buffer, 0, PAGE_SIZE);
```

Beautiful, it resembles the 0xDEADBEEF convention.
This is a nice touch, I like it.
Maybe there is some style guide or another advice URL you'd like
to cite for this in a `// comment`?
It just seems like a kindness to other folks debugging *their* modules.

I do have a concern about it, though.
The crypto community has a whole DSE (dead store elimination) [literature](https://www.usenix.org/sites/default/files/conference/protected-files/usenixsecurity17_slides_zhaomo_yang.pdf) about
those mean old compilers optimizing out a buffer clear like this one, see e.g. [sodium_memzero()](https://doc.libsodium.org/memory_management).
At least in user space, it is often the case that a compiler
can prove that clearing a secret password buffer has "no effect",
or that code trying to read the buffer would have "undefined behavior".
Changing the compiler flags can mean the difference between
zeroing or not zeroing.
So we maybe want a second comment here about recommended
flag settings where we observed via https://godbolt.org or similar
that the zeroing actually happened.

---

In the Makefile I confess I don't know why `M=$(PWD)`
is necessary, but I imagine it truly is.

---

Looks good, very clear.
This code achieves its design goals.

I would be happy to delegate or accept maintenance tasks on this codebase.

---

EDIT

> "on a multi-core machine, the text [might not] fit within PAGE_SIZE"

There is a spec of sorts for cpuinfo output text,
such as being comprised of "x : y\n" lines.

There's no real size limit on how much output it could produce.
When going from a uniprocessor to dual-, quad-, 8-core machines
we see that its length increases, without any fixed bound.

It seems plausible to me, though not guaranteed,
that uniprocessor output (first core output)
would usually fit within PAGE_SIZE.
I was looking to make that explicit,
and also to make it clear that once we see "model name : y"
we require that any subsequent mention must also say "y".
If we saw e.g. "...i3-3220 CPU @ 3.30GHz" and subsequently
saw "...i3-3220 CPU @ 1.00GHz" we would be sad.

### bounce buffers

Arbitrary limits can often be designed out of an algorithm.
So for example we might `malloc(n)` rather than
declare `char buf[80]`.
Or we might do stream processing, which I briefly described above.

Arbitrarily define MAX_LINE to be 127, large enough for consumer to
parse any line it is interested in.
Define BUFSIZE to be some larger power of 2 such as 128.
Allocate three such buffers and ask that they be aligned on cache lines,
such as kmalloc() offers.
(Allocate a fourth buffer,
and ignore part of it,
if requesting aligned allocations is inconvenient.)

Consumer reads from result buffer and never from either private bounce buffer.

Define `get_line()` which issues reads, finds next newline,
and strcpy's next line into the result buffer.
It's a fixed-size result buffer so long lines get truncated.

Init with a BUFSIZE-byte read to fill the first bounce buffer,
and set an `end` index to the amount read.
Set `current` index to `0`.
Define a `buf_num()` helper that maps an index to 0 or 1.

Each request to get another line will use `memchr` to
find next `\n` newline in the valid portion of current buffer.
If not found, issue a BUFSIZE-byte read for the alternate buffer,
updating `end`, and scan for newline again.
Possibly it's not found and
we set a NO_NEWLINE flag and set `newline` index to end of that buffer,
corresponding to a very long line.

Now we perform two copies to the result buffer:

- from `current` to either `newline` or end-of-current-buffer
- if needed, from start-of-alternate-buffer to `newline`

Write a `\0` at end of result buffer.
Now a (possibly truncated) line is ready for the consumer.

If NO_NEWLINE is set, continue to read buffers and scan for newlines.
Stop when you hit newline or EOF.
That way we can maintain the invariant that
upon entry `current` always points to the
start of line that will be returned to consumer,
as long as valid characters remain.
On many processors it will take multiple reads
to skip past the somewhat verbose "flags:" lines.

Update `current` to point just past the newline.
Return the result buffer.

> Can you elaborate a bit on the sanity check you mentioned?

I was just advocating that we replace `strchr(line, ':')`
with the slightly more picky `strstr(line, ": ")`.
Do I believe the colon will always be followed by SPACE?
Yes, I do, it's part of the cpuinfo spec.
But I'd like to express that in the code.

> I feel like I could mock this edge-case by manually creating a file to test this behavior?

Yes, you could definitely arrange for the OP target code
to see a buffer which ends with `": "` or with just `":"`,
and arrange for a Red test to turn Green.

> how do you feel about the function returning a const char* instead of a char*?

I missed that. Good catch!

Yes, definitely mark it `const`.

Comment: (1/2)
Thanks for the feedback! Regarding your point "on a multi-core machine, the text [might not] fit within PAGE_SIZE" - can you elaborate a bit on that, maybe with an example? 
I don't fully understand your proposed solution with bounce buffers. Ideally I would like this function to be as resilient as possible, so it works on "most" systems. 
Also you mention: "... by bad luck the : colon appears at end of buffer ...". Good catch, that could happen. Can you elaborate a bit the sanity check you mentioned?

Comment: (2/2) I feel like I could mock this edge-case by manually creating a file to test this behavior?
Also, how do you feel about the function returning a const char* instead of a char*?

Comment: I fleshed it out a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

**Micro optimization**

`char *colon_pos = strchr(line, ':');` replaceable with `char *colon_pos = strchr(line+10, ':');` as per prior code.